# How to match a string pattern up to first character occurence

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse off some specific URLs from a HTML source and I wrote the following regex that is supposed to match a URL pattern up to the very first space character occurrence:

`/https:\/\/sub.domain.com\/202\S[^ ]*/g`

For some reason, if there are multiple spaces it won't stop to the first space.

As an example, I'm expecting the regex applied on the following string
`"https://sub.domain.com/2020/05/24/another-path/       </span>
    </button>
    <div"`

to match `https://sub.domain.com/2020/05/24/another-path/`

https://regex101.com/r/0iaNg4/1

I know that there are severeal questions on the same topic, but can't really figure out how to make my regex non-greedy

Comment: Replace `\S[^ ]*` with `\S+`. However, you should not parse HTML with regex directly,

Answer (score 0):

replace \S[^ ]* to \S+

like this :

/https://sub.domain.com/202\S+/g

:)